# Python: How to populate new Pandas dataframe columns with data from existing columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, timeserieschart

Can someone help me out? I am getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

from the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

testdf = pd.read_csv('../../IBM.csv')

print testdf
print "------------"
testdf['NHigh'] = 0
print testdf

if testdf['Close'] > testdf['Open']:
    testdf['Nhigh'] = testdf['Close'] * testdf['High']

print "********"
print tested
```

What I am trying to do is create a new column populated by values from two
existing columns but only if a condition is true.

The shape is a stock dataframe with the following columns - `Open, High, Low,
Close` etc and I want to add a new column (`NHigh`) based on an operation between
say `Close` and `High` if `Close` is > than `High` for that row.

Thanks if you can help....

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print testdf
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
Date_Time                                                  
1997-02-03 09:04:00  3046.0  3048.5  3046.0  3047.5     505
1997-02-03 09:27:00  3043.5  3043.5  3043.0  3043.0      56
1997-02-03 09:28:00  3043.0  3044.0  3043.0  3044.0      32
1997-02-03 09:29:00  3044.5  3044.5  3044.5  3044.5      63
1997-02-03 09:30:00  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0      28
1997-02-03 09:31:00  3045.0  3045.5  3045.0  3045.5      75

print testdf['Close'] > testdf['Open']            
Date_Time
1997-02-03 09:04:00     True
1997-02-03 09:27:00    False
1997-02-03 09:28:00     True
1997-02-03 09:29:00    False
1997-02-03 09:30:00    False
1997-02-03 09:31:00     True
dtype: bool

testdf.loc[testdf['Close'] > testdf['Open'],'Nhigh'] = testdf['Close'] * testdf['High']
testdf['Nhigh'] = testdf['Nhigh'].fillna(0)
print testdf
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume       Nhigh
Date_Time                                                              
1997-02-03 09:04:00  3046.0  3048.5  3046.0  3047.5     505  9290303.75
1997-02-03 09:27:00  3043.5  3043.5  3043.0  3043.0      56        0.00
1997-02-03 09:28:00  3043.0  3044.0  3043.0  3044.0      32  9265936.00
1997-02-03 09:29:00  3044.5  3044.5  3044.5  3044.5      63        0.00
1997-02-03 09:30:00  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0      28        0.00
1997-02-03 09:31:00  3045.0  3045.5  3045.0  3045.5      75  9275070.25
```

Other solution use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
testdf['Nhigh']=np.where(testdf['Close'] > testdf['Open'], testdf['Close']*testdf['High'], 0)
print testdf
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume       Nhigh
Date_Time                                                              
1997-02-03 09:04:00  3046.0  3048.5  3046.0  3047.5     505  9290303.75
1997-02-03 09:27:00  3043.5  3043.5  3043.0  3043.0      56        0.00
1997-02-03 09:28:00  3043.0  3044.0  3043.0  3044.0      32  9265936.00
1997-02-03 09:29:00  3044.5  3044.5  3044.5  3044.5      63        0.00
1997-02-03 09:30:00  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0  3045.0      28        0.00
1997-02-03 09:31:00  3045.0  3045.5  3045.0  3045.5      75  9275070.25
```